# My mechanical rig bones in the eye aren't lining up with my meta-rig, how do I fix this?

Tags: armature, bones, rigify

I'm trying to rig my eyes, and make them follow the target that rigify automatically puts there, by parenting the eye ball to a mechanical bone. I made sure to place the bone in the correct place in the eye with my meta-rig. The problem is that the mechanical bones are not lining up with the meta-rig, except in edit mode. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my meta-rig:
[image: meta-rig for the eye]

And then the mechanical bones in the generated rig(object mode):
[image]

in Edit mode:
[image]

Comment: I see you are new to this community. Your first question might go unanswered for days or weeks, but don't give up with second, third and subsequent questions. Btw, I am not sufficiently up-to-date with 2.90.